# Problems with SQL syntax DATEADD

Tags: sql, oracle, dateadd

```
SELECT hd.holiday_code, 
       hd.holiday_duration, 
       hdep.departure_date                                    AS 'Start Date', 
       Dateadd(day, hd.holiday_duration, hdep.departure_date) AS 'End Date' 
FROM   holiday_details hd 
       INNER JOIN holiday_departure hdep 
               ON hd.holiday_code = hdep.holiday_code
```

Well i've been trying to get this specific code ^ to work, but i cant figure out the dateadd syntax. It looks right from what i have research on the googles, but i always get the error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

This is usually caused my some minor error on my part, but i cant find it after looking for about 20 minutes. Can anyone point out the error that is probably staring me in the face

Comment: `Dateadd` is TSQL not Oracle.

Comment: Check out the manual for a list of date time functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#i88891

Comment: Wow me getting my languages confused. Todate?

Comment: As I understand it, ORACLE uses INTERVAL notation.  `hdep.departure_date + INTERVAL hd.holiday_duration 'DAY'`.  *(I worked that out on a phone, with google, and it took longer to type than to find.)*

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the number of days with a numeric value.  Another problem with your syntax is in 'Start Date' and 'End Date'; replace single quotes with double quotes. Change your query for something like this:

```
SELECT hd.holiday_code, 
       hd.holiday_duration, 
       hdep.departure_date AS "Start Date", 
       hdep.departure_date + hd.holiday_duration AS "End Date" 
FROM   holiday_details hd 
       INNER JOIN holiday_departure hdep 
               ON hd.holiday_code = hdep.holiday_code
```

Hope it helps.